# Writing Permission for Facebook 3.0 SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have successfully loaded the sign in and sign out method into my application. I would like to get write permission on click of a button. (Talking about the alert box that comes like Application name is trying get permission to publish)

Is this possible?

It tried:

```
Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.OPENED))
        {
            session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
```

Doesn't work. Can somebody direct me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will check for the publish permission and if the session doesnt have this then it will create a request for new permission.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();    
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
             .NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS);
     session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

}
```